# Cross column search in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, search

I have dataframe with columns `source_image_name`, `dest_image_name`, `score`. The rows have duplicates where the `source_image_name` is in the `dest_image_name` and vice-versa. I am trying to remove this occurrence.

I've tried iterating using iterrows() and filters. I created hashes of image names and stored them in new columns before searching.

**Eaxmple Dataframe**

> | source_image    | dest_image    | score     |
>
> |--------------   |-------------  |-------    |
>
> | image_1.jpg     | image_2.jpg   | 5         |
>
> | image_2.jpg     | image_1.jpg   | 5         |
>
> | image_3.jpg     | image_4.jpg   | 10        |
>
> | image_4.jpg     | image_3.jpg   | 10        |
>
> | image_3.jpg     | image_5.jpg   | 9     |

```
df["hash_source"] = df["source_image"] + df["dest_image"] 
df["hash_dest"] = df["dest_image"] + df["source_image"]    
df["is_delete"] = 0    
for idx,item in df.iterrows():
    # Set column value to mark the row for deletion
    if item["is_delete"] == "0":
        df[df["hash_dest"]==item["hash_source"]]["is_delete"] = 1
```

I am expecting to find an efficient way to identify those rows. I was thinking of calculating numerical hash for each image name and add them up into a column to find duplicate rows. However I think there would be collisons while doing so.

**Output Dataframe**

> | source_image    | dest_image    | score     |
>
> |--------------   |-------------  |-------    |
>
> | image_1.jpg     | image_2.jpg   | 5         |
>
> | image_3.jpg     | image_4.jpg   | 10        |
>
> | image_3.jpg     | image_5.jpg   | 9     |

Comment: do you just want these rows to disappear? Is the binary relation shown in your example guaranteed for all the repeated names?

Comment: I want the first occurence of the row to disappear. Unfortunately I dont see the binary relation across the entire dataset. However I can seperate the non-binary ones from the dataframe if there is a solution for the binary ones.

Comment: So let's say that `dest_image` of row 1 has the same name of `source_image` of row 2, but `dest_image` of row 2 don't have the same name of `source_image` of row 1. What is the expected result in this case?

Comment: That is a valid row, which I would like to keep in the dataframe. I am trying to identify the rows where the `source`, `dest` are inverted so I can delete one of them. I've update the code where I append the filenames for comparision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of hashes is the good direction, but you don't need to go to the lenght to hashing.
It's enough to concatenate the `source_image` name and `dest_image` name in lexicographical order. So, if the two names are switched, you end with the same control string. Then you can search for duplicates in the control column and drop them.

This should be quite efficient:

```
def joinnames(x):
    return ''.join(sorted([x['source_image'], x['dest_image']]))

df['control'] = df.apply(joinnames, axis=1)
df['dupes'] = df.duplicated('control', 'first')
finaldf = df.loc[~df['dupes']]
```

Using the sample dataframe provided, the above code produces the following `finaldf` dataframe:

```
  source_image   dest_image  score                 control  dupes
0  image_1.jpg  image_2.jpg      5  image_1.jpgimage_2.jpg  False
2  image_3.jpg  image_4.jpg     10  image_3.jpgimage_4.jpg  False
4  image_3.jpg  image_5.jpg      9  image_3.jpgimage_5.jpg  False
```

Now you just need to drop the `'control'` and `'dupes'` columns and you're done.

If you are unsure of how some of the methods work, here the resources: [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html),  [pandas.DataFrame.duplicate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), [pandas indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).